# What is a reasonable command to prompt for sudo password with sudo -A?

Tags: macos, sudo

My question is definitely related to [What option should I give the sudo command to have the password asked through a graphical interface?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23494/what-option-should-i-give-the-sudo-command-to-have-the-password-asked-through-a)

But my question is slightly different. I know how to use sudo and SUDO_ASKPASS. But I'm still learning the Mac OS X conventions, etc.

My question is: Is there a reasonable default graphical program or command to run when running sudo -A? This is an automated solution so it's not a problem if that program requires arguments; it probably should, at least an argument like what prompt to show the user. I'll write them out to a shell script and execute that (which I'm already doing, and already works, but it's my little home-grown cross-platform UI which doesn't fit in well on OS X).